# ORA-00972 when use Japanese fields name

Tags: oracle, field-names

I have a oracle table with Japanese field name as "日本語項目分類カナ名称", when I select 日本語項目分類カナ名称 from myTable, I got error as below:

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
Cause: An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
Action: Specify at most 30 characters.
```

what can I do? this table is used by a lot of app, I can't modify field name...

Comment: What is the actual SQL statement you're using?

Comment: select 日本語項目分類カナ名称 from myTable

Comment: Are you running Oracle 12.2 and do you have the `COMPATIBLE`  initialization parameter set to `12.2` or higher so you can use up to 128 byte column names?

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: @MTO what can I do next?

Comment: How can you create a table with column name longer than 30 characters? It is not possible that such table exist.

Comment: I think Japanese Name is reason,  if use DBCS code, "日本語項目分類カナ名称" len is 2x10=20, but if use UTF-8, it might be 4x10=40.